# Getting ErrorAccessDenied when calling EWS GetItem

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS in Exchange, and when I authorize as an attendee of a meeting, and I sent a GetItem request, I get the following:

```
<m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
<m:MessageText>Access is denied. Check credentials and try again., The 
process failed to get the correct properties.</m:MessageText>
<m:ResponseCode>ErrorAccessDenied</m:ResponseCode>
<m:DescriptiveLinkKey></m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
<m:Items/>
</m:GetItemResponseMessage>
```

If I authorize as an organizer, I'm able to get the data without the error.  Also, in Outlook 365 (UI) I'm able to see an event and responses even if I'm an attendee of a meeting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ItemId of the meeting on the attendee's calendar or that of the meeting on the organizer's calendar.  Using the attendee's credentials, you'll only be able to see the item on attendee calendar, which should probably suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm using the ItemId of the meeting on the organizer's calendar - that's the only one I have access to.  Is there a way to get the attendee's ItemId given the organizer's ItemId?

Comment: So you won't get the organizer's item on his calendar if you authenticate with attendee's credentials, and vice-versa.  That said, if you can see responses to the invites in the O365 UI when you are logged in as an attendee, then there must be something on the attendee's item that holds this info, or perhaps another EWS call that I'm unaware of that would get this info for a meeting.  I might suggest using the EWS Editor (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ewseditor) to take a close look at the attendee's item to see what might help there.